# Google Sheets Array Generation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is it possible to generate an array of numbers between two provided numbers
eg `=sequence(1,10)` results in `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

My end goals is to generate a list of days between two dates, but have tried to generalise the question.

I thought about using [`=TREND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263), but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(row(1:10))
```

returns a list of numbers 1 through 10, as a column. Can be made a row with `transpose`.

A dynamic version, where the upper bound is taken from cell C1:

```
=arrayformula(row(indirect("1:" & C1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, That works well, I thought from this I'd be able to get a series of dates dynamically, However, I've now got stuck on replacing the `10` with `days(today(), $B$1)`

Comment: See the edit. Reference C1 could be any formula.

Comment: champion, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also do same using `DATE` function, this gives you ability to generate months or years.

Pretending start date is written in `A2` and end date is written in `B2`.
This formula will generate a list of dates between (inluding start, excluding end).

`=ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(A2), MONTH(A2), DAY(A2) + SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D"), 1, 0, 1)))`

#### Few explanations:

`DATE` function has ability to move over month if days is over last day of that month of that year. Same goes for months.

`DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D")` gives you amount of days between the dates. You can `+ 1` if you want to include end date.

`SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D"), 1, 0, 1)` generates number from 0 to amount of days generated above.